# Trying to set Label.Text leads to NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, winforms, label, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to change the text of a label in C#.NET.

I am using `HjälpText.Text = "Hjälp mig.";`

When running in debug mode, the code throws the following exception

> NullReferenceException was unhandled.
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You should mention (by tagging) the technology you are using, i.e. `winforms`, `webforms`, `wpf` etc.

Comment: More detail/source code should be provided for us to be of more help.

Comment: It would seeem that your `HjälpText` has been declared but not initialized. You'll have to provide more information/code to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my problem.

edhedges has led me to look at my code and I noticed that I misplaced where the line of code was. It was not in the "_Load" method, but before the method that initializes the components.